# Achievement notification

Tags: user-behavior, material-design, gamification

This is for a web app for users Male/Female, Between 15-35 yrs old. Cant reveal more sorry :S

Whats better for the user?

Option A: Notification when an achievement has been made (you can tap it an go to the achievements page) and Also if you open the menu you`ll see a "+1" number in the achievement section so you can enter into it and review your achievements

Option B: A notification that prompts in your screen that says what achievement you've reached and the award (You have to tap/click "ok" to dismiss the notification)and Also if you open the menu you`ll see a "+1" number in the achievement section so you can enter into it and review your achievements

I believe the "Option A" its better for my own experience on things like this but the real question is what the majority thinks.

Comment: This might be easier to follow with mockups or wiresframes. There is a balsamiq plugin where you can sketch it. like how annoying is the pop up, where is it what does it block how much does it contrast with the other items. Its hard to tell verbally.

Comment: It unfortunately is going to depend a lot on context. A notification that pops up and blocks the screen until you hit "ok", for example, would not be appropriate for a map based driving app. A small harder to notice notification that you have to click into to know the achievement may not be appropriate for a game whose sole purpose is reaching these achievements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop-up window interrupts users' current workflow. Thus, in my opinion, just like yours, I would avoid it.

However, without wireframes or mockups, it is hard to tell whether your first option is better than the second pop-up option. It is good if you could manage to design the notification to blend in the application, instead of a pop-up. An example can be seen here: https://medium.com/budi-brain/designing-in-app-survey-6163304e88dd#.7apxypf2w In the section of "Understanding the user", and then "ask gently", the second image in the middle explained the blend-in concept well. The example is designed for surveys, not notifications. But I think notification is similar in terms of its positioning within the user flows when users are interacting with the product.